# This is a Question about a bug. What does your computer think mayonnaise has to do with cougar attacks?

Tags: bug

I was browsing to see if there had been any Questions about taking precautions or defending against cougars. (There had been.)  Questions about bears came up in the search -- that's reasonable.  But this question about mayonnaise also came up.  Mayonnaise?  It didn't even talk about spoiled mayonnaise attracting cougars. [How long does mayonnaise last unrefrigerated in the back-country?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/how-long-does-mayonnaise-last-unrefrigerated-in-the-back-country)  I don't expect a serious answer to this, or a fix.  I think it is funny.  Computers aren't ready to take over yet!

Comment: So you're reporting a bug with the SE search algorithm? I don't really understand your question....

Comment: @Erik There is not much to understand.  A search for cougars turns up mayonnaise.  This is odd.  Ignore it or tweak the search algorithm, whichever you prefer.   As I said: "I don't expect a serious answer to this, or a fix. I think it is funny."  Sorry if I have wasted people's time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not trying to say you didn't get the results you got, or that you're wasting anyone's time. I just don't know what search terms you used to get your mayonnaise result.

I tried [cougars](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=cougars) and got 22 mayonnaise free results.

I tried [precautions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=precautions) and I got 91 results. I scanned the first 50 and didn't see mayonnaise.

I tried [cougar precautions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=cougar%20precautions) and I got 1 mayonnaise free result.

I don't work for StackExchange/StackOverflow so I couldn't fix the problem even if I could reproduce it. I think if you give us the query/search terms you used then we could answer why mayonnaise was in the result set.

Comment: OK, I'll try for the mayonnaise again later today and report.

Comment: I couldn't get the mayonnaise back -- I don't remember the exact wording of the test question I formulated to see if anyone had asked about cougars.  I get geocaching, exploding rocks, shoelaces, igloos, less noisy Tyvek, and sandstorms, along with many other irrelevant Questions by asking "What should I do if I encounter a cougar?" or "What precautions should I take to avoid cougars" or "How can I protect myself against cougars?"  The search engine seems to put major weight on "What" and "How" and minor weight on the actual subject of the query.  Mayonnaise remains a mystery, but who cares?

Comment: @ab2 That is basically what I was expecting. It was probably keying on a common word as a search term. Searching with key terms instead of questions will probably give you better results in most search engines.

Comment: *mayonnaise free results* LOL